# Generate Hilbert matrix Fortran

Tags: matrix, fortran

I'm just starting off in Fortran and I'm trying to generate a very simple 4x4 Hilbert matrix but my output is a bunch of zeroes, apart from a 1 at the start. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
PROGRAM HILBERT
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL :: a(4,4)
REAL :: i, j

!Initialise matrix a with non zeroes
 i = 1.0
 j = 1.0

DO  i = 1,4,1
 a(i,4) = 0.0 
 DO  j = 1,4,1

a=1.0/(i+j-1.0)     !Attempt to generate Hilbert matrix

  WRITE(6,'(f3.0)',advance='no') a(i,j)   !formatted output

 END DO
    write(6,*) !formatted output
END DO 

END PROGRAM HILBERT
```

Comment: In addition to the answers: don't use `real` variables for the `DO`s.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from your given code:

```
PROGRAM HILBERT
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL :: a(4,4)
REAL :: i, j


DO  i = 1,4 ! The third argument is not necessary if equal to 1
 DO  j = 1,4
  a(i,j) = 1.0/(i+j-1.0) ! generate Hilbert matrix

  WRITE(6,'(f8.5)',advance='no') a(i,j)   !formatted output
 END DO
 write(6,*) !formatted output
END DO 

END PROGRAM HILBERT
```

The initialization of `i` and `j` is not necessary, because the loop does this automatically.

Your initialization of `a(i,4) = 0` should be `a(i,j) = 0`, but this is not necessary. Following M.S.B.'s advice, you could do this initialization at the beginning with `a = 0`, but this is not necessary in this case.

A very important thing: Your format code **doesn't show** the fractional part of the numbers.

And: According to the newer standards, loop variables (`i` and `j` in this case) have to be integers, because the behaviour of real numbers is ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks very much for your time, my format line was holding me back alright. She's up and running now and I can finally get around to calculating her determinant.

Answer (score 1):

`array=scaler` sets all elements of the array to the scaler.  Try `a(i,j)=...`

Answer (score 0):

In addtion to the corrections @M.S.B. and @Stefan point out, you can also more efficiently (in terms of code and error-proneness) create such a matrix with the `forall` statement:

```
program hilbert
  implicit none
  real a(4,4)

  integer i,j

  forall(i=1:4, j=1:4) a(i,j) = 1/(i+j-1.0)

! As @Stefan says, the format is an important part of the answer
  print '(4F8.5)', a

end program hilbert
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the forall statement, seems like a right time saver!